# How to have a friendly-url for a custom liferay action

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

We are using Liferay 6.2.10 EE.

I have created a custom action referencing [doc](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-and-adding-struts-actions#adding-struts-actions).

As part of the implementation, I read a parameter from the request (an articleId) and redirect to the appropriate web content article.

My url looks like: /c/portal/solution

*This works!*

My requirement is to have friendlyUrls like:: /c/portal/solution/123456

I know we have achieve this by custom portlet, as discussed here: [Dynamic URLs for a Liferay Portlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690134/dynamic-urls-for-a-liferay-portlet)

Is there a way to implement this with **hooks**?

I could not get any reference and I could not find any element like "friendly-url-routes" in liferay-hook.xml.

I asked this question on liferay forum too just in case their is some documentation for this:
https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/75378827

Thanks!

Comment: [speaking of friendly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site)... please add the suggested information - on all your posts, not just here

Comment: @OlafKock, thanks for pointing that. I have added the reference of my post on liferay forum too.